# high level Kafka consumer api not work

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

I setup a single node kafka and try a simple pub/sub pattern like that :

From my Laptop i produce some messages by code :

```
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("bootstrap.servers", "192.168.23.152:9092");
    props.put("acks", "all");
    props.put("retries", 0);
    props.put("batch.size", 16384);
    props.put("linger.ms", 1);
    props.put("buffer.memory", 33554432);
    props.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
    props.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");

    Producer<String, String> producer = new KafkaProducer<>(props);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        producer.send(new ProducerRecord<String, String>("tp3", Integer.toString(i), "hello " + Integer.toString(i)));

    producer.close();
```

and I also written a Simple Consumer :

```
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("bootstrap.servers", "192.168.23.152:9092");
    props.put("group.id", "g1");
    props.put("client.id","client1");
    props.put("enable.auto.commit", "true");
    props.put("auto.commit.interval.ms", "1000");
    props.put("auto.offset.reset", "latest");
    props.put("session.timeout.ms", "30000");
    props.put("key.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
    props.put("value.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
    KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(props);
    consumer.subscribe(Arrays.asList("tp3"));
    while (true) {
        ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(100);
        for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records)
            System.out.printf("offset = %d, key = %s, value = %s", record.offset(), record.key(), record.value());
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1000);
    }
```

**But the Consumer did not retrieve anything**

Anyone please explain to me what happened  ? 
I' m sure the producer work well , because i use console command to retrieve messages and it worked perfectly ( i attach proven image here ) 
[image]

Any helps is appreciated :( :( :(

Comment: In case people are wondering about the version, it's 2.11-0.10.0.0 (as seen in the screenshot). I'm struggling with the same thing. The producer works fine, but the consumer API does not want to work whatever I do. I'm running mostly the same code as you, except I'm using localhost and "enable.auto.commit" to false.

Comment: I'm testing a bit with configuration parameters. I increased the poll time to 1000 and 5000, and when running the consumer, it actually works - sometimes So there are some timinig issues here, which I haven't identified yet.

Comment: I connected them through Vpn (our Vpn policy ban many ports ) , I haven't been granted to access 9092 port so I must use sock proxy to connect through , I think it 's major reason ,  My doubts are just only "why i used sock proxy with many others case and they worked well :( :( but failed with Kafka

Comment: If you are wondering if there are vpn/firewall issues, just try localhost to see if it works or not.

Comment: tks @Yngvar Kristiansen , i tried and it works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

According to the Kafka [FAQ](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/FAQ#FAQ-Whydoesmyconsumernevergetanydata?):

> **Why does my consumer never get any data?**
>
> By default, when a consumer is started for the very first time, it ignores all existing data in a topic and will only consume new data coming in after the consumer is started. If this is the case, try sending some more data after the consumer is started. Alternatively, you can configure the consumer by setting auto.offset.reset to "earliest" for the new consumer in 0.9 and "smallest" for the old consumer.